# Zend Framework: error_reporting

Tags: zend-framework

Could anyone tell me where to place error_reporting(E_ALL) on a ZF production site?

I'm thinking it should go in application/default/bootstrap.php but it's not logging anything in the error_log file located in htdocs/logs. the file is there but it remains empty. the access_log file in the same dir does get new entries.

The rights of error_log are 674, same as access_log. When I change it to 676 (write for all) it makes no difference.

There are many errors including an "Application Error" at the top of the homepage, which I'm trying to find the cause of.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have it in the beginning of `scripts/application_bootstrap.php`

Also, put in application.ini:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

to control if the errors are displayed on the Web page.

Then, make sure you have `log_errors = On` in your Apache's `php.ini`.